# automatically update mysql field based on value of other field

Tags: php, mysql

I have a mysql table for subscription details

It has a start_date, end_date and status field

Now, what i would like to do is whenever end_date of subscription is reached, i would like the status field to change from active to inactive

for example when end_date > curdate, update subscription table set status=inactive

Is there a way to run a check at the end of each day to check and update this?

how can i do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the `cron job` in `linux` based server to check and manipulate the data in db with php

Answer (score 2):

Why not just create a view and calculate the status. Then use the view instead of the table:

```
CREATE VIEW vwSubscription
   AS 
  SELECT
      start_date,
      end_date,
      IF(end_date > curdate, 'inactive', status) as status
  FROM subscription
```

Answer (score -1):

what you need to write is a script that runs in the background like this

```
while (true) {
   echo 'updating';
   //check rows here
   echo 'done';
   sleep(10);
 }
```

Just execute it in the shell (php -f script.php) and put that in the background and it will do what you want. Just remember that memory is important. Make sure you unset($var) everything on each cycle so your memory usage doesn't go through the roof.

Comment: Why [reinvent](http://wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) the [wheel](http://wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Task_Scheduler)?

Comment: I do it a lot, it is something very useful. I run most of my sites with back end cli scripts.